# problema de velocidad con owl-carousel boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy intentando hacer un owl-carousel, pero no puedo establecer la duración de cuanto se muestra cada imagen, busque jQuery, estoy algo exhausto analizando el código y manoseándolo, (las imagenes las borre, pero las dejo el código por si acaso) el código:
html:

```html
<section id="clients" class="wow fadeInUp">
  <div class="container">
    
    <header class="section-header">
      <h3 id= "clients">Nuestros Clientes</h3>
    </header>
    
    <div class="owl-carousel clients-carousel">
      <img src="img/clients/client-1.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/clients/client-2.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/clients/client-3.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/clients/client-5.png" alt="">
      <img src="img/clients/client-6.png" alt="">
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section><!-- #clients -->

<!--==========================
Clients Section
============================-->
<section id="testimonials" class="section-bg wow fadeInUp ">
  <div class="container">
    
    <header class="section-header">
      <h3>testimonios</h3>
    </header>
    
    <div class="owl-carousel testimonials-carousel">
      
      <div class="testimonial-item">
        
        <h3>cliente1 </h3>
        
        <p>
          <img src="img/quote-sign-left.png" class="quote-sign-left" alt="">
          texto.
          <img src="img/quote-sign-right.png" class="quote-sign-right" alt="">
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="testimonial-item">
        <h3>cliente 2</h3>
        
        <p>
          <img src="img/quote-sign-left.png" class="quote-sign-left" alt="">
          texto
          <img src="img/quote-sign-right.png" class="quote-sign-right" alt="">
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="testimonial-item">
        
        <h3>cliente 3</h3>
        
        <p>
          <img src="img/quote-sign-left.png" class="quote-sign-left" alt="">
          texto
          <img src="img/quote-sign-right.png" class="quote-sign-right" alt="">
        </p>
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

css (que he copiado y pegado en varias partes)

```css
elemento {
  transform: translate3d(-3330px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
  width: 7770px;
}
```

Aclaro que usé funciones jQuery, así que como último de mis recursos posteo acá, gracias colegas

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, en vez de usar owl-carousel estás creando uno desde cero. ¿Por qué no usas owl-carousel? Edit: He visto que tienes el HTML de la estructura del owl-carousel, así que si que debes de estar usándolo. ¿Has usado la documentación web que te proporciona? Es bastante completa y tienes multitud de demos que se ajustan a casi cualquier caso de uso.

Comment: efectvamente lei la documentacion y encontre fragmentos de codigos que tampoco me funcionaron, probe autoplay, transition(este me funciono pero solo mueve mas lento , pero no hace que la pausa sea mas extensa) entonces quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes usar `autoplayTimeout` y establecer un tiempo en ms, por defecto viene en 5000, si lo que quieres es que las imágenes tengan una pausa mayor, aumenta el valor a por ejemplo 8000.

```
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 8000,
```

La velocidad del autoplay se maneja con `autoplaySpeed` para hacer mas lento o mas rápido varía el número en ms.

```
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 8000,
autoplaySpeed: 5000,
```

---

**Añado**

Te recomiendo que hagas uso del plugin del siguiente modo:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Owl CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css"> 
  
  <!-- Owl JS -->       
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random">
    </div>            
    
  </div>  
  
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:8000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  })
})
</script>
</html>
```

Para tener dos o mas carousels con distintos parámetros se los diferencia en la configuración de la inicialización.

Ejemplo inline con 2 carousels identificados por id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owlUno = $('#carousel-uno');
  var owlDos = $('#carousel-dos');
  var owlConfig = {
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 8000,
    autoplaySpeed: 500,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  };
  // activamos el primero
  owlUno.owlCarousel(owlConfig);
  // modificamos el config para el segundo
  owlConfig.autoplayTimeout = 3000;
  owlConfig.autoplaySpeed = 1500;
  owlConfig.responsive[600].items = 4;
  // activamos el segundo
  owlDos.owlCarousel(owlConfig)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id=carousel-uno class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=1">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=2">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=3">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=4">
  </div>
</div>

<div id=carousel-dos class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=10">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=20">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=30">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=40">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=50">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=60">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=70">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random=80">
  </div>
</div>
```

ref: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: la verdad es que soy nuevo en este tema, ya probe incluir esto en el html y en bootsrap.min.css y en ninguno funciona, en que parte iria correctamente?  me podrias dar una ejemplo mas especifico? te lo agradeceria mil, ya que justamente eso esta en los metodos que probé.

Comment: Lo que debes modificar es tu archivo .js del owl-carousel. Si te descargaste la librería, ve a la ruta `src/js/owl.autoplay.js` y en línea 121, puedes cambiar el valor.
Una vez hecho esto, llama ese archivo .js al final de tu html.

Comment: También puedes llamar a la librería completa, y luego añadir únicamente los valores por default del autoplay dentro de un <script>

Comment: el tema que estoy ocupando trae lib/owlcarousel la cual incluye owl.carousel y owl.carousel.min y una carpeta asset, ahora acabo de descargar owlcarousel2.3 , el archivo que me dices solo lo extraigo en owlcarousel extraigo toda la carpeta src y la pego en la carpeta raiz del proyecto?

Comment: Haz algo, yo supondría que tienes una carpeta CSS y otra carpeta llamada JS. Busca dentro de la librería que descargaste los archivos `owl.carousel.css` y `owl.carousel.js` y muevelos a sus respectivos lugares. Una vez que los hayas "llamado" dentro de tu html (css en la cabezera del documento y js al final), puedes incluir un <script>. Dame un momento y ya modifico mi respuesta para explicarme mejor